# How to center my navbar items?

Tags: html, css, navigation, center, navbar

I have been checking on other questions related to mine, and most of the time "text-align:center" is suggested. However, even if I implement it to my code, the navbar still doesn't center... Here's my code:

```css
/* NAVIGATION BAR */

#navigation {
 width:1300px;
 height:auto;
}

#nav {
    width: auto;
}

.ulnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.navli {
 float:left;
}

.navli a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navli a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.navli.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index:1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display:block;
}

.active {
 background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
<div id="nav">
<ul class="ulnav">
  <li class="navli"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="navli"><a href="#news">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink 1</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.1</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.2</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink3.1</a>
   <a href="#">Droplink3.2</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink3.3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="navli"><a href="#news">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the text in the nav items or the nav items themselves?

Comment: I mean the nav items themselves, sorry for the mislead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `float:left` on your navli class ang set it to `display:inline-block` and add `text-align:center` on your `#nav`, and to center your `#navigation` add `margin:0 auto;`

```css
/* NAVIGATION BAR */

#navigation {
 width:1300px;
 height:auto;
    margin : 0 auto;
}

#nav {
    width: auto;
    text-align : center;
}

.ulnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.navli {
 /* float:left;*/
   display : inline-block;
}

.navli a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navli a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.navli.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index:1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display:block;
}

.active {
 background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
<div id="nav">
<ul class="ulnav">
  <li class="navli"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="navli"><a href="#news">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink 1</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.1</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.2</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink3.1</a>
   <a href="#">Droplink3.2</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink3.3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="navli"><a href="#news">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! I thought myself too, that the float left is restricting it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `float:left` on the `li`, which aligns them to left. I've removed it and added `text-align:center` to the `ul`

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
/* NAVIGATION BAR */

#navigation {
 width:1300px;
 height:auto;
}

#nav {
    width: auto;
}

.ulnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align:center;
}

.navli {
 display:inline-block;
}

.navli a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navli a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.navli.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index:1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display:block;
}

.active {
 background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
<div id="nav">
<ul class="ulnav">
  <li class="navli"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="navli"><a href="#news">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink 1</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.1</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.2</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink 2.3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown navli">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Droplink3.1</a>
   <a href="#">Droplink3.2</a>
      <a href="#">Droplink3.3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="navli"><a href="#news">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but what exactly did you change? EDIT: I see you did what Allan suggested also.

Comment: 1. Removed float:left from the li and added display:inline-block
2. Added text-align:center to the ul

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that while posting this. Glad that you're problem is solved!